# $query = sprintf not updating MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a forgot password script, however i'm getting caught up slightly.

The issue is, `$query = sprintf("UPDATE`users`SET`password`= '%s' 
                      WHERE`email`= '$forgotpassword'",
                mysql_real_escape_string($newpassword));` is not updating the data in the field 'password'.

The 'forgot' value is updating as needed. And again, I know the script is connecting to the database as the forgot field is updating to '1' as needed.

Heres the code:

```
//Generate a RANDOM MD5 Hash for a password
$random_password=md5(uniqid(rand()));

//Take the first 8 digits and use them as the password we intend to email the user
$emailpassword=substr($random_password, 0, 8);

//Encrypt MD5 format for the database
$newpassword = md5($emailpassword);

    // Make a safe query
    $query = sprintf("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '%s' 
                      WHERE `email` = '$forgotpassword'",
                mysql_real_escape_string($newpassword));

    $query = sprintf("UPDATE `users` SET `forgot` = '1' 
                      WHERE `email` = '$forgotpassword'");

                mysql_query($query)or die('Could not update members: ' . mysql_error());
```

I know this version of MYSQL is depreciated, but it's what this project has to use. Just got to go with me on that one.

Cheers

Comment: Using `%s` to do your escaping isn't a bad idea if you're stuck with this antiquated interface, but you should use it consistently to be clear you're escaping things correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't calling `mysql_query($query)` with the first update, only the second.

```
// Make a safe query
$query = sprintf("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '%s' 
                  WHERE `email` = '$forgotpassword'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($newpassword));

// NEED TO CALL mysql_query($query); HERE

$query = sprintf("UPDATE `users` SET `forgot` = '1' 
                  WHERE `email` = '$forgotpassword'");

mysql_query($query)or die('Could not update members: ' . mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

You're composing two queries but only executing one.

Comment: Perhaps OP's new prescription glasses haven't come in yet?

Comment: Quick quiz: What method is used to execute a query? If you have two queries, how many calls should there be?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the password is not updated because the WHERE clause doesn't match any row ... are you sure you have set the email in `WHERE`email`= '$forgotpassword'` ?